# ASP.NET MVC 6: How to add resource file using project.json?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using an assembly that needs an external configuration file to be in bin folder to work properly. It seems that new way to do it in MVC 6 is to include reference in project.json file. Despite the [detailed project.json docs](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) I had no success in it.

Answer (score 2):

The project.json file should contain a "resource" definition with your config file. You can then access the resource using a manifest resource.

**project.json**

```
{
  ...
  "resource": "bin/somefile.config",
  ...
}
```

This can also include wildcards and arrays of values if necessary.

***.cs**

```
string resourceName = "ProjectName.bin.somefile.config";
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

Note that the config file included slashes without a project name, but the resulting resource name includes the project name and converts slashes to dots.

**Troubleshooting**

If you are getting back `null` for your resource stream, it can help to set a breakpoint and examine the output of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to use "resource" in the project.json and then compile my project the output window indicates the following:

```
warning DOTNET1015: The 'resource' option is deprecated. Use 'embed' in 'buildOptions' instead.
```

So I guess that's the preferred approach now.